# How to call multiple store procedure in controller codeigniter?

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter, stored-procedures

I have a problem when I want to call more than one stored procesure in the controller. just only one stored procedure that execute.

This query stored procedure in the model :

```
function getKategori(){
    $query = $this->db->query("call KategoriSelectPro('id_kategori','kategori')");
    return $query->result();
}

function getEditSubKategori($id_subkategori){
    $query = $this->db->query("call SubKategoriEditSelectPro(?,'id_kategori','kategori','sub_kategori')", $id_subkategori);
    return $query->row_array();
}
```

and this code in controller:

```
function subkategoriedit($id_subkategori = ''){
        $data['kategori'] = $this->madmin->getKategori();
        $data['editsubkategori'] = $this->madmin->getEditSubKategori($id_subkategori);
}
```

The problem is only one function of the model can be called in the controller. example:

`$data['kategori'] = $this->madmin->getKategori();` (SUCCESS)

`$data['editsubkategori'] = $this->madmin->getEditSubKategori($id_subkategori);` (NOT RUN)

The error message is :

> Commands out of sync; you can't run this command now

so if reversed.

help me, how to call multiple store procedure in CodeIgniter?

Comment: your $id_subkategori has value or not

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem a couple of moments earlier, searched for it on stackoverflow, found the answer and forgot to rate the answer .. anyhow

add the following function in file
      system > database > drivers > mysqli > mysqli_driver.php

```
function next_result()
    {
        if (is_object($this->conn_id))
        {
            return mysqli_next_result($this->conn_id);
        }
    }
```

and then add the following command after every calling query you perform.

```
$this->db->next_result();
```

it worked like a charm for me ..

Answer (score 0):

in your model change return $query->row_array(); to return $query->result_array();

```
function getKategori(){
    $query = $this->db->query("call KategoriSelectPro('id_kategori','kategori')");
    return $query->result();
}

function getEditSubKategori($id_subkategori){
    $query = $this->db->query("call SubKategoriEditSelectPro(?,'id_kategori','kategori','sub_kategori')", $id_subkategori);
    return $query->result_array();
}
```